Are ideas related to a finished project a distraction from my current project?
I'm a new postdoc in a sub-field of mechanical engineering that is different from the sub-field I did my PhD in (I did my PhD in ML for combustion and now I'm doing a postdoc in ML for general fluid dynamics). I'm noticing an interesting phenomenon -- as I get up to speed with the literature in the new field and learn new things/concepts, I constantly get ideas on how to tackle old problems that we never solved with my PhD advisors. For example, I'm now studying convolutional neural networks for the first time, and certain concepts from there brought me new ideas on how one could improve an aspect of my PhD work. I seem to be getting many more ideas related to my past work than related to my current postdoc project. My PhD work was really fascinating to me which could explain why my brain still keeps thinking about it. But I'm wondering if those ideas are actually a distraction from my current project given that I don't have time (or only very limited time) to pursue them now. I would like to be making progress in my postdoc project because it's new and interesting to me.
It seems to me that I have three options when one such idea arises:

Ignore it and try to bring my focus back to my postdoc work. Perhaps with time my brain will learn to generate only ideas related to the current project? (Something like mindfulness, but applied to research :))
Don't ignore it, note it down in my ideas notebook, with hopes that maybe in 2, 5, 10 years I will have the resources to explore it.
Pursue means to dig into that idea asap if my past advisors think it's a good idea. For example, I could chat with my past advisors about it to find out whether they think it's a promising direction, and then together we could try to find researchers who could help us do the work.

So far, I've been doing 2. and occasionally texting my PhD advisors to see what they think. Some of those ideas they said are an interesting direction. But it never goes beyond that small brainstorming with them and jotting some more detailed notes in my ideas notebook. So the result is that my notebook keeps growing in size as I keep reading new literature in the new field, but it never leads to me pursuing an idea. What I need right now are ideas related to my current postdoc project, and those aren't so frequent... (Yet?)
What would you recommend I do? 1., 2., 3., or perhaps something else? In case you think that I can keep doing 2., would you say that every idea is worth jotting down, or perhaps I should develop an idea-filtering strategy?
Extra question: Do you think that more ideas related to my postdoc project will keep coming as I make more progress in the new field?
Some more info:

I'm officially/unofficially mentoring two new PhD students of my past advisors, so I might have some ability to introduce a student to one of the promising ideas. But I'm also aware that they already have a defined PhD project and I'm not their advisor. I would also never force a student to do a specific thing, because they have the right to organize their PhD work themselves. They might find my ideas not interesting or rewarding to pursue and that's okay.
I plan to stay in academia but I have no intention to come back to my PhD field (combustion) in the future. Currently other fields interest me more as a long-term research plan. I wouldn't mind doing a small project related to combustion in the future, but I wouldn't center my research proposal or a grant around it.
My PhD advisors seem to be happy to keep collaborating with me in the future.


I fear that this is an individual choice and different answers apply to different people along with what opportunities they have.
But, my preference, especially in the early career is for 2. Keep a notebook, well organized and up to date on each project. Set aside an hour or two each week to review the notebook(s) and update them whenever you have a "bright" idea.
I'd supplement that with a small deck of index cards that I'd carry everywhere, along with a pen. When I'm on the bus, or whatever, and get an idea for a project (even waking up in the morning), jot down a few words.
Sometimes you get stuck on the main project. Rather than fighting it, you may need a mental break. Go to the notebooks or index cards to "clear the mind" a bit.
If you have a bunch of potential projects you are in a good place to advise students, say, doctoral students.
And, you don't need to wait several years. Some projects "ripen" and are worth following up when that key insight hits, maybe over coffee with a colleague.
When one project winds down and there is little left do that is creative, scan the notebook for the "next big thing."
If you use electronic "notebooks" be aware that your backup media (or cloud providers) may not exist in 10 years. Take precautions.

Thank you, it's useful to hear your perspective. My notebooks are all paper ones ;) Good idea to have a deck of index cards with me! Would you also say that I should learn to steer my focus towards my current project, or are those ideas popping up actually a beneficial thing?

You are currently being paid to do work pertinent to your postdoc. Whether it is your PI or a fellowship, doesn't matter. You should focus on the work that is at hand.
It is tempting to lean back into your PhD research because that is a comfort zone. You feel competent, and now that you have some separation post graduating and likely more clarity on the topic as a whole (after writing a thesis, defending etc), you are naturally getting all sorts of ideas.
Save your ideas, see if you want to pursue them independently. I know I saved mine when I was in a similar situation.... and guess what, when I went independent, those ideas went in the trash, because I had broader experience and bigger ideas, and making derivative work to my PhD was no longer that thrilling.
Also keep in mind. If you end up with a mediocre postdoc because you were very distracted, your odds of continuing in academia will suffer, and so will any opportunity to revisit those ideas.

As a research administrator, I want to share that I agree with this based on what PIs have confided to me. A common problem we have right now is that postdocs don't want to do the projects their PI is working on. The PI is paying you to do the work in their lab. If you want to work on a new idea, you should write the grant that pays your salary. You will quickly find that this is a very gruesome prospect, and it's much easier to endure a couple of years with the PI's project even if less exciting. Unfortunately we don't have money for everyone's pet projects. The money we have is specific.
